# How to set radio button as checked in dart polymer component

Tags: dart, dart-polymer

I need to show green radio buttons as checked based on model value. HTML has two input elements of type radio:

```dart
<input name="color" type="radio" id="red" value="red"></label>
<input name="color" type="radio" id="green" value="green" checked>
```

Dart code has a variable colorValue='green'. How can the checked attribute of input element be set based on dart variable? Can this be done in HTML or this must be done in dart code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```dart
<input ... checked?="{{colorValue=='green'}}">
```

Comment: Thanks for the help. Now I know how to use this, but is this syntax documented somewhere yet?